# Drag and Drop in Sectioned Recycled View XamarinAndroid

Tags: xamarin.android

Is it possible to have feature like drag and drop in Sectioned RecyclerView?

I found github link for drag and drop within RecyclerView. But I want it to implement it in sectioned recyclerview.

[Sectioned Recycler View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NYA5.png)

Please suggest

```
 void OnDragInsideRecyclerView(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        var theEvent = e.Event;
        var view = (View)theEvent.LocalState;
        var containerView = (RecyclerView)sender;

        _currentContactPosition = containerView.GetChildAdapterPosition(view);

        // Ensure the position is valid.
        if (_currentContactPosition != -1)
        {
            _contactToMove = _adapter.MainViewModel.Contacts[_currentContactPosition];
        }

        switch (theEvent.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Location:
                View onTopOf = containerView.FindChildViewUnder(theEvent.GetX(), theEvent.GetY());
                _newContactPosition = containerView.GetChildAdapterPosition(onTopOf);

                // Ensure the new position is valid.
                if (_newContactPosition != -1)
                {

                    var layoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager)_recyclerView.GetLayoutManager();
                    int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.FindFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                    int lastVisiblePosition = layoutManager.FindLastVisibleItemPosition();

                    // Scroll up or down one if we are over the first or last visible list item.
                    if (_newContactPosition >= lastVisiblePosition)
                        layoutManager.ScrollToPositionWithOffset(firstVisiblePosition + 1, 0);
                    else if (_newContactPosition <= firstVisiblePosition)
                        layoutManager.ScrollToPositionWithOffset(firstVisiblePosition - 1, 0);

                    // Update the location of the Contact
                    _adapter.MainViewModel.Contacts.Remove(_contactToMove);
                    _adapter.MainViewModel.Contacts.Insert(_newContactPosition, _contactToMove);
                    _adapter.NotifyItemMoved(_currentContactPosition, _newContactPosition);
                }
                e.Handled = true;
                break;

            case DragAction.Ended:
                // Reset the visibility for the Contact item's view.
                // This is done to reset the state in instances where the drag action didn't do anything.
                view.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;

                // Boundary condition, scroll to top is moving list item to position 0.
                if (_newContactPosition != -1)
                {
                    _recyclerView.ScrollToPosition(_newContactPosition);
                    _newContactPosition = -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    _recyclerView.ScrollToPosition(0);
                }

                e.Handled = true;
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Add your code attempt. Did you try this ? http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidDragAndDrop/article.html

Comment: My code is almost similar like mentioned in above link but my requirement is different I want to drag and drop between recycler view  having section headers.

Comment: can you detail the question with code which you have tried ? where you have struck exactly?

Comment: I have added this code which is working fine for normal recycler view but I want to implement that thing in sectioned recycle view shown in image

Comment: I'm following that link  https://github.com/C0D3Name/DragDropDroid

Comment: No ready made components available for Sectioned Recycler View in Xamarin Android. So you can create native android binding project to convert the SectionedRecyclerView .jar to .dll. 
1. https://bintray.com/truizlop/maven/sectionedrecyclerview/1.2.0
2. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/

Comment: Can you please help me out for my situation I have invested more than a week but didnt get any solutions